# How to refuse planned responsibilities at current job when planning to resign

Tags: job-search, resignation

I am job hunting currently, and have a couple of potential offers. Of course, before I have an official job offer in hand and resign, I will do everything I am supposed to do and fulfill my responsibilities.

However, there are a few projects that are in the planning and will start in a couple of months, and my manager wants to distribute responsibilities to team members. Because I am already planning to move on, I don't feel comfortable making promises.

I wonder if there are good ways to politely refuse taking on future responsibilities.

Comment: What do you mean by "potential offers"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do nothing different.

Act as if you will be there indefinitely. Competent managers know employees leave. That's part of their planning, normally. Until you have an offer acting like you do is foolish.

It's not a promise. If you don't get an offer, you'll be there. Until you are resigning don't act like you are in your notice period.

Many countries and states have at will employment. This means you -- and the company -- can terminate employment at any time for any reason.

The company won't feel "bad" if they have to lay you off. Your attitude is nice, but not at all reciprocated by them..